# Error of import in nodejs: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

Using mocha as a framework for testing nodejs.

When importing functions from a controller file to be tested, I got the error in the photo attached. The same import statement is used in another controller file and it works fine.

Where can be the problem, is it in the testing framework?

In the controller file, the statement to export functions is:
`module.exports = {function}`

In another controller file and in the testing file, the statement to import functions is:

```
var {function} = require('the path of the controller file where functions are')
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVFCt.png)

Comment: from the photo , i think the problem is inside your function .

Comment: But the function works fine when it is imported into the other file.

Comment: can you send a photo of your code

Comment: You mean a code of the function?

Comment: yes and the path to the file

Comment: I solved the issue thank you.